# GetEntryAssembly method always return null in Android project using MAUI

Tags: android, maui

I'm having a strange problem with MAUI. Using the GetEntryAssembly method in a MAUI project always return null for the Android project. It's working fine for Windows project.
This is the method that I'm using:
`System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = EntryAssemblyAttribute.GetEntryAssembly();`

Anyone has experienced the same problem ? or knows how to solve it ?

Thanks in advance

I alwo try with :
`System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();`
but did not solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android#platform-differences.

Comment: I have tested this and it also return null in the xamarin andorid project. This api seems didn't support on the android.

Comment: I need to be able to get assembly in order to be able to load the resolurces from Android MAUI app,. I'm able to do in Windows app and iOS ,but not in Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks H.A.H
Your answer helped me.

> Read this learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/…. –
> H.A.H.